# The *arguments position in definition of a function

Tags: python

I defined a function like this:

```
def func(must, op1=1, op2=2, op3=3, *arguments, **keywords):
    print(must, op1, op2, op3)
    for arg in arguments:
        print(arg)
    for kw in keywords.keys():
        print(kw, ":", keywords[kw])
```

I called it:

```
func(1, op1=1, op2=2, op3=3, 1, 3)
```

Of course, I got an error:

[Error information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gah6z.png)

In my mind, `*arguments` are positional parameter. And the `op1`, `op2`, `op2` are keyword parameters. So `*arguments` should be before `op1`, `op2`, `op3`. Then I changed the definition:

```
def func(must, *arguments, op1=1, op2=2, op3=3, **keywords):
    print(must, op1, op2, op3)
    for arg in arguments:
        print (arg)
    for kw in keywords.keys():
        print (kw, ":", keywords[kw])
```

Why doesn't the Python interpreter think the first definition is a mistake?

Hi All,
I updated this topic.

After discuss with my colleague, I think that:

1. definition of a function, the parameters are default or non-default parameters
2. call a function, the parameters are positional or keyword parameters

So, whether the parameter is a positional parameter depends on you call the function, not define the function.

Comment: Post the error as text please. Don't post images of console output.

Comment: I'm not sure why the downvotes. You have a legitimate question here and you've clearly made an attempt to understand it on your own.

Comment: Please go through slide 8 to 30. https://www.asmeurer.com/python3-presentation/slides.html#8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While slightly counterintuitive, the first definition is completely unambiguous:

```
func(must, op1=1, op2=2, op3=3, *args, **kwargs)
```

This means that `op1`, `op2`, and `op3` are optional positional arguments. You can't specify any of `*args` without explicitly setting all three first. You got the error because you attempted to place positional arguments after keywords. It's irrelevant that the keywords name positional arguments. You can make the same call like this:

```
func(1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3)
```

That will not raise an error. Neither will

```
func(1, 2)
```

In that case, only `op1` will have a non-default value, `*args` will be empty, and you can set whatever keywords you want, including `op2` and `op3`.

Aside from `*args`, all positional arguments are named and can be passed in by keyword as well. In practice, though, all arguments that come after the first one passed in as a keyword *must* be passed in as a keyword. It therefore follows that you can't pass in `*args` if you pass in any named positional argument as a keyword.

In your second example, you've made the op arguments keyword-only by placing them after the splat (`*`). Any positional arguments after the first are therefore absorbed into `*args`.

Keep in mind that keyword-only arguments don't need defaults. A function like `def func(*, a): pass` can *only* be invoked as `func(a=3)` and never as `func(3)`.

On a side note, the splat argument is conventionally named `*args` and the splatty splat one `**kwargs`. I have stuck with that convention throughout my answer.

Answer (score -1):

At the first example, you can call your function like this (it's still working):

```
func(9, 9, 9, 9)
```

Python determine which parameter is `keyword` when you call a function.

Here's more example:

```
def func(a,b,c=1,d): # -> a, b, c, d are parameters and c has default value = 1
     pass

func(1, 2, 3, 4) # -> call with 4 postional parameters

func(1, 3, d=3) # -> call with 2 positional parameters and 1 keyword parameters
```

Comment: Please add more information to your answer.
1. Why op1, op2 and op3 are not keyword parameters.
2. Why seconde code snippet works.

Comment: Yes, it works, But this call treat all parameters as position parameters, which don't meet my expectation, e.g. I want call something like this:
func(1, op2=4, 7, a=1, b=2)